# Python Pandas vs R. Transformation Code Conciseness

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

I converted this R code:

```
# Raw data
data <- data.frame(
    metalname=c('Al','Cd','Cr','Co','Cu','Au','Fe','Pb','Mo','Ni','Pt','Au','Ta','Ti','W','Zn'),
    radius=c(0.1431,0.1490,0.1249,0.1253,0.1278,0.1442,0.1241,0.1750,0.1363,0.1246,0.1387,0.1445,0.1430,0.1445,0.1371,0.1332),
    crystal=c('FCC','HCP','BCC','HCP','FCC','FCC','BCC','FCC','BCC','FCC','FCC','FCC','BCC','HCP','BCC','HCP'))

# Calc lattice parameters (nm)
data <- rbind(
    transform(subset(data, crystal=='BCC'), N=2, latticea=4*radius/sqrt(3), latticec=0),
    transform(subset(data, crystal=='FCC'), N=4, latticea=2*radius*sqrt(2), latticec=0),
    transform(subset(data, crystal=='HCP'), N=6, latticea=2*radius, latticec=4*radius*sqrt(2/3))
)
```

to this Pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from pandas import DataFrame

# Raw data
data = DataFrame({
    'metalname': ['Al','Cd','Cr','Co','Cu','Au','Fe','Pb','Mo','Ni','Pt','Au','Ta','Ti','W','Zn'],
    'radius': [0.1431,0.1490,0.1249,0.1253,0.1278,0.1442,0.1241,0.1750,0.1363,0.1246,0.1387,0.1445,0.1430,0.1445,0.1371,0.1332],
    'crystal': ['FCC','HCP','BCC','HCP','FCC','FCC','BCC','FCC','BCC','FCC','FCC','FCC','BCC','HCP','BCC','HCP']
})

# Calc lattice parameters (nm)
databcc = data[data.crystal=='BCC']
databcc['N'] = 2
databcc['latticea'] = 4*databcc.radius/math.sqrt(3)
datafcc = data[data.crystal=='FCC']
datafcc['N'] = 4
datafcc['latticea'] = 2*datafcc.radius/math.sqrt(2)
datahcp = data[data.crystal=='HCP']
datahcp['N'] = 6
datahcp['latticea'] = 2*datahcp.radius
datahcp['latticec'] = 4*datahcp.radius*math.sqrt(2/3)
data = databcc.append(datafcc).append(datahcp)
```

The code works, but is there a way to make the Python version more concise? Ideally, I would be able to do the multi-column calculation in a single step without temporary variables like the R code. Is this possible?

Comment: in python 2.7 math.sqrt(2/3) will be 0, you need to specify 2.0/3.0 to use floating point division

Comment: I am using Python 3, but I know, you're absolutely right regarding Python 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be very fast as its all vectorized

```
In [65]: data.join(
              concat([ 
                DataFrame(dict(N=2, latticea=4*data.loc[data.crystal=='BCC','radius']/np.sqrt(3))), 
                DataFrame(dict(N=4, latticea=2*data.loc[data.crystal=='FCC','radius']/np.sqrt(2))), 
                DataFrame(dict(N=6, latticea=2*data.loc[data.crystal=='HCP','radius'], 
                                    latticec=4*data.loc[data.crystal=='HCP','radius']/np.sqrt(2/3.0))) 
                    ]))
Out[65]: 
   crystal metalname  radius  N  latticea  latticec
0      FCC        Al  0.1431  4  0.202374       NaN
1      HCP        Cd  0.1490  6  0.298000  0.729948
2      BCC        Cr  0.1249  2  0.288444       NaN
3      HCP        Co  0.1253  6  0.250600  0.613842
4      FCC        Cu  0.1278  4  0.180736       NaN
5      FCC        Au  0.1442  4  0.203930       NaN
6      BCC        Fe  0.1241  2  0.286597       NaN
7      FCC        Pb  0.1750  4  0.247487       NaN
8      BCC        Mo  0.1363  2  0.314771       NaN
9      FCC        Ni  0.1246  4  0.176211       NaN
10     FCC        Pt  0.1387  4  0.196151       NaN
11     FCC        Au  0.1445  4  0.204354       NaN
12     BCC        Ta  0.1430  2  0.330244       NaN
13     HCP        Ti  0.1445  6  0.289000  0.707903
14     BCC         W  0.1371  2  0.316619       NaN
15     HCP        Zn  0.1332  6  0.266400  0.652544

[16 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: this is almost exactly (a subset) what I had in the original post. Are you suggesting anything different at all? That is far longer and far less readable than the R version and still uses temporary variables.

Comment: where exactly does this use a temporary variable? it is returning a new frame.

Comment: Your code just does one of the steps. In the full operation, I split the dataframe into three, add three new columns using different equations, and append back into the final data frame. In that case, databcc would be a temporary intermediate variable.

Comment: wow! With your new code, it is concise, does not use intermediate temporary variables, and does not require a separate expression language hacked into strings. That is perfect. This is fully comparable to the R version. Thanks! btw, I made a fix and minor change.

Answer (score 4):

This is a use case for the new `query`/`eval` functionality in pandas 0.13

```
databcc = data.query('crystal == "BCC"')
sqrt3 = sqrt(3)
databcc.eval('latticea = 4 * radius / sqrt3')

# ...
```

There's currently no way to call a function in an expression string, so you have to define a local variable and use that instead.

Comment: Python syntax can't accommodate this scenario, so we have to escape out into a separate expression string language? If the premise of pandas was to port R functionality to a cleaner language platform, it would seem that Python was the wrong choice.

Comment: So, just to understand you, you think that typing the extra two single quotes is enough of a reason to rethink the impetus of pandas?

Comment: You're downplaying it as merely typing two quote characters, but those quotes are effectively escaping out of Python into a completely separate language which is a terrible solution. If the Python syntax is inadequate for the needs of the product, then yes, it should definitely have used another platform. There is no shortage of options.

Answer (score 1):

Does this equivalent to original question code looks better than original R masterpiece:

```
import pdb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from pandas import DataFrame

# Raw data
data = DataFrame({
    'metalname': ['Al','Cd','Cr','Co','Cu','Au','Fe','Pb','Mo','Ni','Pt','Au','Ta','Ti','W','Zn'],
    'radius': [0.1431,0.1490,0.1249,0.1253,0.1278,0.1442,0.1241,0.1750,0.1363,0.1246,0.1387,0.1445,0.1430,0.1445,0.1371,0.1332],
    'crystal': ['FCC','HCP','BCC','HCP','FCC','FCC','BCC','FCC','BCC','FCC','FCC','FCC','BCC','HCP','BCC','HCP']
})

def calc_lattic_params(x):
    N = None
    l = None
    lc = None
    if x['crystal'] == 'BCC':
        N = 2
        l = 4 * x['radius'] / math.sqrt(3)
    elif x['crystal'] == 'FCC':
        N = 4
        l = 2*x['radius'] / math.sqrt(2)
    elif x['crystal'] == 'HCP':
        N = 6
        l = 2*x['radius']
        lc = 4*x['radius']*math.sqrt(2.0/3.0)

    return pd.Series({'N': N, 'latticea': l, 'latticec': lc})

data = pd.concat([data, data.apply(calc_lattic_params, axis = 1)], axis = 1)
```

Comment: This is the best python solution so far. The R one is still nicer though. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Incanter (Lisp-based) version for comparison if anyone is interested:

```
(use '(incanter core stats charts))

; Raw data
(def data (dataset [:metalname :radius :crystal] [
    ["Al" 0.1431 "FCC"]
    ["Cd" 0.1490 "HCP"]
    ["Cr" 0.1249 "BCC"]
    ["Co" 0.1253 "HCP"]
    ["Cu" 0.1278 "FCC"]
    ["Au" 0.1442 "FCC"]
    ["Fe" 0.1241 "BCC"]
    ["Pb" 0.1750 "FCC"]
    ["Mo" 0.1363 "BCC"]
    ["Ni" 0.1246 "FCC"]
    ["Pt" 0.1387 "FCC"]
    ["Au" 0.1445 "FCC"]
    ["Ta" 0.1430 "BCC"]
    ["Ti" 0.1445 "HCP"]
    ["W" 0.1371 "BCC"]
    ["Zn" 0.1332 "HCP"]
]))

; Calc lattice parameters (nm)
(conj-rows
    (add-derived-column :latticec [] (fn [] 0)
    (add-derived-column :latticea [:radius] (fn [r] (/ (* 4 r) (sqrt 3)))
    (add-derived-column :n [] (fn [] 2)
        ($where {:crystal "BCC"} data))))
    (add-derived-column :latticec [] (fn [] 0)
    (add-derived-column :latticea [:radius] (fn [r] (* 2 r (sqrt 2)))
    (add-derived-column :n [] (fn [] 4)
        ($where {:crystal "FCC"} data))))
    (add-derived-column :latticec [:radius] (fn [r] (* 4 r (sqrt (/ 2 3))))
    (add-derived-column :latticea [:radius] (fn [r] (* 2 r))
    (add-derived-column :n [] (fn [] 6)
        ($where {:crystal "HCP"} data)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is comparison of *code conciseness* (`Python` vs `R`), here is an `R` solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data, key="crystal")
data_transformed_dt <- rbind(dt["BCC", .(metalname, radius, crystal, N=2, latticea=4*radius/sqrt(3), latticec=0)],
                             dt['FCC', .(metalname, radius, crystal, N=4, latticea=2*radius*sqrt(2), latticec=0)],
                             dt['HCP', .(metalname, radius, crystal, N=6, latticea=2*radius, latticec=4*radius*sqrt(2/3))])
```

The advantage of setting `key="crystal"` is that it indexed the crystal column, just like the index in a database. This will save the searching time (`"BCC"`, `"FCC"` ...) tremendously if the data set is very large.

---

Another way to go about this would be to create another *key* data.table as follows:

```
# v1.9.5+, for new feature "on = ", See github project page
require(data.table) 
key = data.table(crystal = c("BCC", "FCC", "HCP"), 
                 latticea = c(4/sqrt(3), 2*sqrt(2), 2),
                 latticec=c(0,0,4*sqrt(2/3)), 
                 N = c(2,4,6))
```

Then we can update the original `data` while joining as follows:

```
setDT(data)[key , c("latticea", "latticec", "N") := 
                  .(radius * latticea, radius * latticec, N), 
              on = "crystal"]
#     metalname radius crystal  latticea  latticec N
#  1:        Al 0.1431     FCC 0.4047479 0.0000000 4
#  2:        Cd 0.1490     HCP 0.2980000 0.4866320 6
#  3:        Cr 0.1249     BCC 0.2884442 0.0000000 2
#  4:        Co 0.1253     HCP 0.2506000 0.4092281 6
#  5:        Cu 0.1278     FCC 0.3614730 0.0000000 4
#  6:        Au 0.1442     FCC 0.4078592 0.0000000 4
#  7:        Fe 0.1241     BCC 0.2865967 0.0000000 2
#  8:        Pb 0.1750     FCC 0.4949747 0.0000000 4
#  9:        Mo 0.1363     BCC 0.3147714 0.0000000 2
# 10:        Ni 0.1246     FCC 0.3524220 0.0000000 4
# 11:        Pt 0.1387     FCC 0.3923028 0.0000000 4
# 12:        Au 0.1445     FCC 0.4087077 0.0000000 4
# 13:        Ta 0.1430     BCC 0.3302444 0.0000000 2
# 14:        Ti 0.1445     HCP 0.2890000 0.4719350 6
# 15:         W 0.1371     BCC 0.3166189 0.0000000 2
# 16:        Zn 0.1332     HCP 0.2664000 0.4350294 6
```

This should be extremely memory efficient and fast, because we update by reference (and no the entire join is not materialised). `on = "crystal"` performs a join on that column and finds matching row indices in `data` corresponding to each row in `key`, and on those matching rows, we simultaneously update/create the necessary columns.

Note that the original order of the data is also preserved in the result.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the improvement and thanks for making `data.table` such a great package! It is `data.table` that let me decide to learn `R`. (BTW: Although I'm using `v1.9.5`, I have to reinstall `data.table` to run your code. )